# Convert specific PDF file to HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, pdf

is there any way how to covert PDF to HTML? I need a text from the file and when I tried PDFtoText library, I got the text, but unsorted and without any rules for parsing.
I noticed, that some PDFtoHTML online services works great with the file. So, any tips please? [Here is the PDF file](http://gymjev.cz/soubory/jidelnicky/2011-2811-0212.PDF) and I need only one specific row in the right column.

Comment: You should try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2249962/765854 and only take the portion that you care about.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956508/convert-pdf-to-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try integrating the PDFtoHTML from the poppler project; that should support table recognition.

Answer (score 0):

pdftohtml works fine : fast, stable but the html result is ugly at best. I have used it for quite some time for a web site that has many job resumes.

It is a good solution for extracting textual content however.

I would give the scribd API a try

http://www.scribd.com/developers/api

or the google apps document API. GOogle does a great job a displaying and converting pdf files

Comment: Source : stackoverflow.com/questions/956508/convert-pdf-to-html