# Converting PDF to HTML

Tags: php, html, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert PDF to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956508/convert-pdf-to-html)

I need to convert resumes that are uploaded in PDF format to HTML.  I am already converting doc and docx formats using livedocx.com, but they don't support converting from PDF.  I have already read the other posts on stack overflow regarding this matter and the standard solution is the install the pdf2html command line tool.  This is not an option for me however since this is a shared hosting server which I am not an administrator of.  The host will not help me by installing the tool, so I either need a third-party service or a clean way to do this with native PHP.  PHP version is 5.2 running on latest CentOS. Please help!

Chris

Comment: Does your host allow you to connect via SSH? If so, you may be able to compile it yourself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956508/convert-pdf-to-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS should have pdftohtml installed by default. That's the tool to be using. If for some reason your hosting provider has removed it then you need to reinstall it. The best thing is for it to be installed through os's package manager. If you have ssh access then log in and install it with:

```
yum install poppler-utils
```

If you don't have ssh access and the service provider isn't willing to install it for you,
guess the only option would be to find a web service similar to what you're using for doc/docx. Don't know of 'a good one', but that's what google's there for.

Answer (score 0):

Another, less elegant solution, would be to use `ghostscript` (which is more likely to be pre-installed) to convert the PDF to PNG images, then display these. This has the advantage of being able to work on more PDF files, and the layout will be kept perfectly, but it will be all images.