# Pdf To Html Conversion

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert PDF to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956508/convert-pdf-to-html)

i have a website template in pdf format ? Is it possible to convert that pdf template into my HTML template?i want to get that pdf design template into an html page/template(i.e containing html tags etc) so that i could modify contents in that template.Please help me.Thank you

Comment: There is no *good* automated way to convert PDF files into a HTML structure. But I'm sure there are some tools with varying levels of quality, which can be found by Googling `PDF to HTML conversion`

Comment: There is a reason people are paid to built websites, because converters never work as well, or as seamlessly as a professional developer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :

1. Convert PDF to Word
2. Open the word file and save as HTML
3. Edit the HTML tags to get rid of MS tags that are not used in your
   page.

or go the hard way and write the HTML page from scratch.

Comment: The hard way? I would call it the best way

Comment: I would call it the best/easy way but it seems he does not have more knowledge in HTML.