# How to block download managers for a website?

Tags: php, html, pdf, download-manager

I have a website where I am using PDFjs viewer to view the PDF. 
But **Internet download manager** or **Download Accelerator Plus** will prompt to download the content PDF. I want to prevent this download managers to download the content PDF.

Is there a way where we can disable this download managers using PHP/HTML?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want someone to be able to download the pdf, don't put it online.

Comment: That is not the solution. Then next solution will be that don't make websites. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should send an `HTTP header` to the client. this header should be `Content-disposition: inline; filename="name.pdf"`. this will show the pdf within browser instead of prompting for download, try it.

Comment: I am using pdfjs viewer where I have provided the url for the pdf to be displayed. When there is any download managers installed on the user system, then it grabs the link and give an option to download the same. I don't want the PDF to be downloadable to the user's system. He can only view the same using the viewer.

Comment: I told you to force server to send the proper header

Comment: I have a code like <div id="viewerContainer" tabindex="0"><div id="viewer"></div></div> and in the Js i am passing url of the file as to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot control client side behaviour. Even with headers set properly, it's all upto the browser (and its extensions) whether the attachment is rendered or downloaded.

Yes, you can try converting pdf to html, and then render that html, or you can give the [scribd API](http://www.scribd.com/developers) a try as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2249962/1066726) answer.